# How to implement a custom listview row with buttons?

Tags: android, listview, event-handling

I have an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) that I want to populate with my custom views of type `NoteView`.  `NoteView` extends LinearLayout and contains two buttons and a checkbox.  I have almost everything working, the `NoteView`'s are being populated with backing data, the lists are getting filled, and the buttons are clickable and perform the required tasks.

The problem is the [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) no longer responds to click/longclick/keypress events at all (other than selecting list items with trackball/DPAD).

I replaced my custom view with a standard TextView and the touch events flowed normally again, so it is almost certainly something I am doing wrong with my custom view or some obscure ListView setting I am overlooking.

Here is my NoteView code and XML Layout.  What am I missing?

```
//Custom Note View
public class NoteView extends LinearLayout{

    private CheckBox mCheckBox;
    private TextView mTitleTextView;
    private TextView mDetailsTextView;
    private TextView mDetailsRightTextView;
    private LinearLayout mButtonLayout;
    private Button mDeleteButton;
    private Button mEditButton;

    //data storage
    private long mNoteId = -1;
    private boolean mStretched = false;
    private CharSequence mDetails = "";
    private CharSequence mStretchedDetails = "";
    private CharSequence mDetailsRight = "";
    private CharSequence mStretchedDetailsRight = "";       


    private NoteView.OnNoteButtonClickedListener mEditNoteListener;
    private NoteView.OnNoteButtonClickedListener mDeleteNoteListener;
    private NoteView.OnNoteCheckBoxClickedListener mCheckboxListener;

    public NoteView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public NoteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }


    private void init(Context context) {

        this.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0);
        this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.noteview_layout, this);//returns the noteview itself, since is parent

        //get views
        mCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.noteViewCB);
        mTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noteViewTitle);
        mDetailsRightTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noteViewDetailsRight);
        mDetailsTextView =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noteViewDetails);


        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(mCheckboxListener != null)
                {
                    mCheckboxListener.onNoteCheckBoxClicked(mNoteId, isChecked);
                }
            }
        });

        //prepare button layout
        mButtonLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.noteViewButtonLayout);
        mEditButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noteViewEditButton);
        mDeleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noteViewDeleteButton);


        mEditButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mEditNoteListener != null)
                {
                    mEditNoteListener.onNoteButtonClicked(mNoteId);
                }
            }
        });

        mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mDeleteNoteListener != null)
                {
                    mDeleteNoteListener.onNoteButtonClicked(mNoteId);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void setOnEditClickedListener(NoteView.OnNoteButtonClickedListener listener)
    {
        mEditNoteListener = listener;
    }

    public void setOnDeleteClickedListener(NoteView.OnNoteButtonClickedListener listener)
    {
        mDeleteNoteListener = listener;
    }


    public void setOnCheckboxClickedListener(NoteView.OnNoteCheckBoxClickedListener listener)
    {
        mCheckboxListener = listener;
    }

    static abstract class OnNoteButtonClickedListener
    {
        public abstract void onNoteButtonClicked(long noteId);
    }


    static abstract class OnNoteCheckBoxClickedListener
    {
        public abstract void onNoteCheckBoxClicked(long noteId, boolean checked);
    }


    public void setNoteId(long noteId)
    {
        mNoteId = noteId;   
    }

    public long getNoteId()
    {
        return mNoteId;
    }

    public void setTitle(CharSequence title)
    {
        mTitleTextView.setText(title);
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked)
    {
        mCheckBox.setChecked(checked);
    }

    public boolean isChecked()
    {
        return mCheckBox.isChecked();
    }

    public void setDetails(CharSequence details, CharSequence stretchedDetails)
    {
        if(details == null || details.length() == 0)
        {
            mDetails = "";
        }else
        {
            mDetails = details;
        }

        if(stretchedDetails == null)
        {
            mStretchedDetails = "";
        }
        else
        {
            mStretchedDetails = stretchedDetails;
        }

        refreshStretched();
    }

    public void setDetailsRight(CharSequence detailsRight, CharSequence expandedDetailsRight)
    {
        if(detailsRight == null || detailsRight.length() == 0)
        {
            mDetailsRight = "";
        }else
        {
            mDetailsRight = detailsRight;
        }

        if(expandedDetailsRight == null)
        {
            mStretchedDetailsRight = "";
        }
        else
        {
            mStretchedDetailsRight = expandedDetailsRight;
        }

        refreshStretched();
    }

    public void setStretched(boolean expanded)
    {
        mStretched = expanded;
        refreshStretched();
    }

    public boolean getStretched()
    {
        return mStretched;
    }

    public boolean toggleStretched()
    {
        setStretched(!getStretched());
        return mStretched;
    }

    public void showButtons() {

        if(mButtonLayout.getVisibility() != VISIBLE )
        {
            Animation slideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(), R.anim.slideonfromright);

            mButtonLayout.setAnimation(slideIn);
            mButtonLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            mButtonLayout.startAnimation(slideIn);
        }       
    }

    public void hideButtons() {
        if(mButtonLayout != null && mButtonLayout.getVisibility() == VISIBLE )
        {
            Animation slideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(), R.anim.slideofftoright);
            slideOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    mButtonLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
            });

            mButtonLayout.startAnimation(slideOut);
        }
    }


    public void hideButtons(boolean noAnimation) {
        mButtonLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
    }

    public void refreshStretched() {

        if(mStretched)
        {
            mDetailsRightTextView.setText(mStretchedDetailsRight);
            mDetailsTextView.setText(mStretchedDetails);
        }else
        {
            mDetailsRightTextView.setText(mDetailsRight);
            mDetailsTextView.setText(mDetails);
        }

        if(mDetailsRightTextView.length() == 0)
        {

            mDetailsRightTextView.setVisibility(GONE);
        }else
        {
            mDetailsRightTextView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        if(mDetailsTextView.length() == 0)
        {
            mDetailsTextView.setVisibility(GONE);
        }else
        {
            mDetailsTextView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

noteview_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="5dip">
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/noteViewCB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/noteViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Title"/>
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/noteViewButtonLayout"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
            <Button android:id="@+id/noteViewEditButton"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/drawngreenbutton"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Edit"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/noteViewDeleteButton"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/drawnredbutton"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Delete"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout  android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/noteViewDetails"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:bufferType="spannable"/>
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/noteViewDetailsRight"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:bufferType="spannable"
    android:gravity="right"/></LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar issue that happends when use a checkbox is in the listview items layout.
Please check if adding the attribute:
android:focusable="false" 
to the checkbox definition helps you like:

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/noteViewCB" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false" />
```

The issue seems to be that Android doesn't allow you to select list items that have elements on them that are focusable.

Best,

Comment: I had the same issue much earlier in development and had found out that focusable="false" was the solution.  Then I changed the layout to my custom view instead of a direct XML layout and forgot to do that again in all my experimenting.  I had tried blocking descendant focusability via xml, but I never went to the individual buttons for focus control.  Thanks, worked perfectly.